# Why does one of my functions just loop back when not meant to?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a simple code guessing game where the user can choose the minimum and maximum number the randomly generated code can be. The user has to try and guess the code to win. When I run my code, the get_range() function works and then it proceeds to the get_guess() function as it should. But when the user enters his/her input for their guess, the code loops back to the start of the get_range() function. Please can anyone help? Thanks in advance. Code:

```
import random
import string

print("Welcome to Code Crunchers!")


def get_range():
    Min = str(input("Enter the minimum number that the code can be: "))
    Max = str(input("Enter the maximum number that the code can be: "))

    Check_Min = Min.isdigit()
    Check_Max = Max.isdigit()

    if Check_Min != True or Check_Max != True:
        print("Input must only contain integers!")
        get_range()
    elif Min == Max:
        print("Minimum and maximum number must not be equivalent!")
        get_range()
    elif Min > Max:
        print("Maximum number must be greater than minimum number!")
        get_range()
    else:

        Random_Number = random.randrange(int(Min), int(Max))

        get_guess()

        return Random_Number


def get_guess():
    Guess = str(input("Enter your guess: "))

    Check_Guess = Guess.isdigit()

    if Check_Guess != True:
        print("Input must only contain integers!")
        get_guess()
    else:
        validate()

    return Guess


def validate():
    Random_Number = get_range()
    Tries = locals()
    Guess = get_guess()
    Length = len(str(Random_Number))
    Digits_Correct = 0

    if Guess == Random_Number:
        print("Well done! You guessed the number in", Tries, " tries!")
    else:
        Digits = ["?"] * Length

        Tries += 1

        for i in range(0, int(Length)):
            if Guess[i] == Random_Number[i]:
                Digits[i] = Guess[i]
                Digits_Correct += 1
            else:
                continue

        if int(Length) > Digits_Correct > 0:
            print("Not quite! You got", Digits_Correct, " digits correct.")
            print(Digits)
            get_guess()
        elif Digits_Correct == 0:
            print("None of your digits match!")
            get_guess()


def play_again():
    Choice = input("Do you want to play again (y/n)?")

    if Choice != "y" or Choice != "n" or Choice != "Y" or Choice != "N":
        print("Please choose a valid option!")
        play_again()
    elif Choice == "y" or Choice == "Y":
        get_range()
    elif Choice == "n" or Choice == "N":
        exit()


get_range()
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're re-calling `get_range()` in `validate()`:

```
def validate():
    Random_Number = get_range() # <-- Here
    ...
```

You might be able to solve this with:

```
def validate():
    Random_Number = random.randrange(int(Min), int(Max))
    ...
```

But overall, that will depend on the direction of your code. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this code:

```
def get_range():
    ... 
    else:
        ...

        get_guess()

        return Random_Number

def get_guess():
    ...
    else:
        validate()

    return Guess

def validate():
    Random_Number = get_range()
    Tries = locals()
    Guess = get_guess()
    ...
```

Suppose you're in `get_guess` and get to the `else` close, so you call `validate`. Here's what happens:

1. `get_guess` calls `validate`
2. `validate` immediately calls `get_range`
3. `get_range` calls `get_guess`
4. now we're back in `get_guess`, see (1)

So your code enters infinite indirect recursion.

Notice how it'll never get past `Random_Number = get_range()` in `validate`, and you're calling `get_guess` in both `get_range` and `validate`.

So, before returning the random number to `Random_Number = get_range()`, `get_range` will try to `get_guess` and immediately discard its return value (that's what `get_guess()` does). Suppose that `get_range` eventually returns. Now you'll call `Guess = get_guess()` again, thus asking the user to guess twice. I think there's a logic flaw here.